# Whats the difference between android themes (Theme, ThemeOverlay, Base.Theme etc)

Tags: android

in the android you have a lot of themes like `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light`, `Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light` and `Platform.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light`.

What is the difference between them and which one should I use?